# VBA Filter Selected cells

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to AutoFilter based on SelectedRange criteria. Ex. user selects cells with "shift" and/or "ctrl", clicks a button, which filters only the values that he had selected.

```
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim arr As String

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    arr = Empty
    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        arr = arr & " " & cel.Value
    Next cel

    x = ActiveCell.Column
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$10:$DV" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I am tried populating a string and concatenating characters so that it looks like the line below, which works, but has fixed values:

```
Range("$A$1:$EZ" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=62, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2", "3", "4"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I've also tried pasting selected values into a range, then transposing and calling the transposed range, however it still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delimited string to get the values from the selected range, then split that into an array to use as your criteria.

```
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim splitstr As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        If splitstr = "" Then 'This avoids an empty index
            splitstr = cel.Value
        Else
            splitstr = splitstr & "|" & cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
    
    x = ActiveCell.Column
    
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Split(splitstr, "|")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$10:$DV" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```